# useContext return undefined

Tags: reactjs, use-context

i tried to use useContext with my react app todo and i get undefined.
i saw some answares in this site and tried some but still get undefined.

this is my createContext file:
`

```
    import React ,{ createContext } from "react";
   const TodosContext = createContext(
      {todos:[]}
   )

export default TodosContext;
```

`

this is my provider file:

`

```
import TodosContext from "./todos-context";
return (
 <TodosContext.Provider value={{todos:todos}}>  
    <Header title={"todos"}/>
    <Input todos={todos} addItem={addItem}/>
    <TodosItems todos={todos} />
    <Footer tabs={tabs} todos={todos} />
 </TodosContext.Provider>

);
```

`
this is my consumer file:

`

```
   import React, { useContext } from "react";
   import classes from "./todosItem.module.css";
    import TodosContext from "../todos-context";

    const TodosItem = (props) => {
    // console.log()
    const todoCtx = useContext(TodosContext);
    console.log(`todoContex : ${todoCtx.name}`);
    }
```

`

Comment: you declare the context as an object of the form `{ todos: todos }`, but you address like `ctx.name`, try `ctx.todos`

Comment: I tried this : console.log(`todoContex : ${todoCtx.todos}`);
Still get undefined.

Comment: Can you please create a live example?